# Why does scope of using directive make a difference?

Tags: c++

Below are two simplified code examples: the first one compiles just fine, the second one emits a compile error (no operator << found which takes a left hand operator ByteVector...).

The only difference in between the two examples is the **placement of the using directive**.

I don't want to know why it fails (you got not enough information to answer this), I am only interested in why it does make *any* difference where I place the `using`.

I would have expected the exact same behaviour in both examples.

**Compiles without error**

```
ByteVector Test()
{
   using Base::operator <<;

   ByteVector foo;
   int bar = 1;
   foo << bar;
   return foo;
}
```

**Compiles with error**

```
using Base::operator <<;

ByteVector Test()
{
   ...same as above, without using
}
```

Extra information:

The operator<< used is defined as follows

```
template<typename T>
ByteVector& operator<<(ByteVector &, const T&){...};
```

Comment: Is "compiles with error" different from "does not compile"??

Comment: It might help if you could post the actual errors maybe?

Comment: The actual error is: binary <<: no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type ByteVector or there is no accetable conversion

Comment: @nabulke and what variants of overload compiler suggests you?

Comment: @ForEveR: The compiler suggests a binary stream operator << (ostream&, const Foo&) which is also visible in that scope. But please remind, I just want to know why the placement of the using makes a difference. I couldn't find anything in the C++ standard about a difference caused by the using.

Comment: As always, post a minimal but **complete** example that shows the problem. Otherwise you're asking people to guess what code you've left out, and that is often not productive.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  If that was the case, you may want to put the `using` directive right after the corresponding `#include`.  As the remark on the page says:

> Putt your using directive at the beginning of the source code file to
>   reduce the potential for unexpected behavior with IntelliSense.

Otherwise, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio. But I don't have any problem with IntelliSense, it doesn't compile! But I check nevertheless if it makes any difference if I place the using at the beginning of the file as you suggested.

Comment: Just tested placing the using at the beginning of the file: it still doesn't compile. It only works if the using is _inside_ of function scope.

Comment: @nabulke I'm sorry it didn't help.

Comment: no need to be sorry. Thanks for your time spent for trying to solve my problem! :-)